# Thread synchronization in DI container managed instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a `FooContext` class that captures some HTTP request-specific runtime values from the request inside an ASP.NET Web API application

```
public class FooContext
{
    private readonly ISet<string> _set = new HashSet<string>();

    public void AddToSet(string s) => _set.Add(s);

    // Copied so that caller won't modify _set
    public ISet<string> GetStrings() => new HashSet<string>(_set);
}
```

Multiple consumers depends on this `FooContext` and will call `AddToSet`/`GetStrings` and depending on the result, run different business logic.

I want to guarantee there will only be one instance per of `FooContext` per HTTP request so I registered inside the DI container as request-scoped (using Autofac here as an example but I guess most containeirs are roughly the same):

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<FooContext>().InstancePerRequest();
}
```

My understanding is, `FooContext` is not thread-safe because threads may call `GetStrings`/`AddToSet` at the same time on the same `FooContext` instance (since it is request-scoped). **It is not guaranteed that each HTTP request will complete on one single thread**.

I do not explictly create new threads nor call `Task.Run()` in my application but I do use a lot of `async-await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which means the continuation may be on a different thread.

My questions are:

1. Is it true that `FooContext` is not thread-safe? Is my understanding above correct?
2. If this is indeed thread unsafe, and I want to allow multiple readers but only one exclusive writer, should I apply a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` on the `ISet<string>`?

## **Update**

Since a commenter comments that my question is unanswerable without showing `FooContext`'s usage, I will do it here. I use `FooContext` in an `IAutofacActionFilter` to capture several parameters that are being passed in the controller method:

```
public class FooActionFilter : IAutofacActionFilter
{
    private readonly FooContext _fooContext;

    public FooActionFilter(FooContext fooContext)
        => _fooContext = fooContext;

    public Task OnActionExecutingAsync(
        HttpActionContext actionContext, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var argument = (string)actionContext.ActionArguments["mystring"];
        _fooContext.AddToSet(argument);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then in other service classes that control business logic:

```
public class BarService
{
    private readonly FooContext _fooContext;

    public BarService(FooContext fooContext)
        => _fooContext = fooContext;

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
         var strings = _fooContext.GetStrings();
         if (strings.Contains("foo"))
         {
             // Do something
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1. Yes.` In practice you won't have an issue as long as you have only one thread running **at a time** for a given HTTP request (in other words - it isn't the multiple threads being used over the lifetime of the request that is the issue - it is two threads accessing it **at the same time** which will cause threading issues). _Have you considered using `ConcurrentDictionary` rather than `HashSet`?_

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for your comment. I did consider using `ConcurrentDictionary`, but due to the fact that I don't actually have key value pairs, I decided to stick to an `ISet`.

Comment: You can ignore the values (or set them to null) - in which case a `ConcurrentDictionary` is basically a `ConcurrentHashSet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is not guaranteed that each HTTP request will complete on one single thread.

When using async/await, the request might run on multiple threads, but the request will *flow* from one thread to the other, meaning that the request will not run on multiple threads in *parallel*.

This means that the classes that you cache on a per-request basis don't have to be thread-safe, since their state is not accessed in parallel. They do need to be able to be accessed from multiple threads sequentially though, but this is typically only a problem if you start storing thread-ids, or any other thread-affinit state (using `ThreadLocal<T>` for instance).

So don't do any special synchronization or use any concurrent data structures (such as `ConcurrentDictionary`), because it will only complicate your code, while this is not needed (unless you forget to `await` for some operation, because in that case you will accidentally run operations in parallel, which can cause all sorts of problems. Welcome to beautiful world of async/await).

> Multiple consumers depends on this FooContext and will call AddToSet/GetStrings and depending on the result, run different business logic.

Those consumers can depend on `FooContext` as long as they have a lifetime that is either `Transient` or `InstancePerRequest`. And this holds for their consumers all the way up the call graph. If you violate this rule, you will have a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/), which may cause your `FooContext` instance to be reused by multiple requests, which will cause concurrency problems.

You do have to take some care when working with DI in multi-threaded applications though. [This documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#multi-threaded-applications) does give some pointers.

Comment: WIthout seeing the calling code at all, we couldn't possibly say whether or not the object is ever accessed from multiple threads in parallel.  Sure, it *might* not, but it also might be, we have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Servy: I would say this information is implied in the question. There could always be some programming error that causes a `FooContext` instance to be cached for too long (for instance because of a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)), but that's not what the question is about. We should be able to assume that OP didn't cause `FooContext` to become a Captive Dependency. Unless OP posts ALL of his code, we can never know for sure there isn't a problem in his code.

Comment: @Servy, I also share the same sentiment. That's why I asked here on SO. The `FooContext` class is written by me and callers are not called from multiple threads *as of today*. But I woud like to include this class in a library so that it can be reused, and that also means I would not be able to foresee how future callers access it. Should I err on the side of caution and still include locking?

Comment: The OP asked if their code is synchronized properly, so you've decided to assume that they synchronized their code properly purely off of the based that they asked if they synchronized their code properly they must have synchronized it properly.  No, the fact that they're asking if they've synchronized their code properly doesn't mean it's safe to assume that they must have synchronized it properly and to conclusively tell them that it's definitely correct.

Comment: @rexcfnghk Whether you want to design your class to be safe to be used from multiple threads, or instead require callers synchronize access to it, is a decision for you to make, based on what you do or don't want to support.

Comment: @Servy: Please re-read the question again. The question is "I have an object that is registered as 'one instance per request'. Should I synchronize access to it." The answer to this question is no, you don't have to.

Comment: @Steven There are *lots* of ways for a consumer to use this type in a thread-unsafe way.  Saying that it's safe, when *it's not*, is just wrong.  It *can* be used in safe ways, if the caller takes care to properly manage the synchronization themselves, instead of relying on this class to do it for them, and it's perfectly fine to choose to design a class that way, but to claim that it can't be used improperly is simply a false statement.

Comment: @rexcfnghk: "Should I err on the side of caution and still include locking?" That all depends, but with this reasoning you would be including synchronization in all classes in your system. This is counter-productive. Instead, document that the class is not thread-safe. As a matter of fact, in .NET, you should always assume that an object is _not_ thread-safe, unless explicitly specified in the documentation.

Comment: @Servy: You should add your own answer.

Comment: @Steven The question isn't answerable.  We *have no idea* if the code is used safely or not because we have no way of knowing how it's used.  It could be used properly, it could not be.  It's not appropriate to post an answer to say the question is unanswerable; that's not how SO works.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not explictly create new threads nor call Task.Run() in my application but I do use a lot of async-await with ConfigureAwait(false), which means the continuation may be on a different thread.

Yes, so it is being accessed in a multithreaded fashion.

> Is it true that FooContext is not thread-safe? Is my understanding above correct?

Yes.

I would say that the calling code is actually in error: `ConfigureAwait(false)` means "I don't need the request context", but if the code uses `FooContext` (part of the request context), then it **does** need the request context.

> If this is indeed thread unsafe, and I want to allow multiple readers but only one exclusive writer, should I apply a ReaderWriterLockSlim on the ISet?

Almost certainly not. A `lock` would probably work just fine.

Using reader/writer locks just because some code does reads and other does writes is a common mistake. Reader/writer locks are only necessary when some code does reads, other does writes, and *there is a significant amount of concurrent read access*.

Comment: Can you please explain further why calling code should not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` here? I don't see how `FooContext` is part of the request context

Comment: It's part of the implicit context. If you consider "context" to mean "any ambient data that is available", then you can't just jump over to a thread pool thread and expect it to work.

Comment: Does that mean that all awaitable dependendies registered in an IoC container, within the context of an ASP.NET (not ASP.NET Core) Web API application, shouldn't be awaited using `ConfigureAwait(false)` as well?

Comment: The reason I ask this is because most of my dependencies are also registered in my composition root in a similar fashion as `FooContext` (most of them are `InstancePerRequest`).

Comment: @rexcfnghk: Any component that isn't thread-safe needs to be accessed only from one thread at a time. If `ConfigureAwait(false)` is causing multithreaded access, then it's a problem.